# How to ignore MySQL connection to database if there is no connection there

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to make parallel database saving in my system. I have two destination that the database will be saved. First in the local computer (so I'm using localhost instead of the IPaddress) and the remote PC (i'm using the IP address to access it).
Here is my code :

```
    static string MyConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=database freq logger;Uid=root;";
    static string MyConnectionString2 = "Server=192.168.41.105;Port=3306;Database=database freq logger;Uid=irfan;";
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
    MySqlConnection connection2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString2);
    MySqlCommand cmd;

public void Read()
{
        while (port.IsOpen)
        {
            try
            {
                if (port.BytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    string message = port.ReadLine();
                    this.SetText(message);
                    connection.Open();
                    try
                    {
                        cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO frequency(value)VALUES(@message)";
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", message);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                    connection.Close();

                    if (connection2 != null && connection2.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        connection2.Open();
                        try
                        {
                            cmd = connection2.CreateCommand();
                            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO frequency(value)VALUES(@message)";
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", message);
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }

                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            throw;
                        }
                        connection2.Close();
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (TimeoutException) { }
        }
    }
```

So I have 2 connectionsql (connection1 and connection2).
And I want to ignore the **connection2** althought the connection is not connect. The connection is ethernet LAN. So when I unplug the LAN, I hope my program still running.
 I always get the error (when I suddenly unplug the ethernet when the program running) in the "connection2.Open();".

I need your help, thank you

Comment: Nearly all your code is wrapped in a `while(port.IsOpen)`. Can you consider the port open when the network cable is unplugged???

Comment: @khargoosh the port is for my serial port that connected to my Arduino, it doesn't matter. The problem is in my connection2 which it connect to another computer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to monitor the connection pro-actively, just trap the resulting Exception and ignore it. Your problem is that your Connection2.Open() is not within the Try{} Catch{} block but outside it.

Try this

```
try
{
    connection2.Open();
    cmd = connection2.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO frequency(value)VALUES(@message)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", message);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection2.Close();
}
catch
{
   // Do nothing - this should continue to work without being able to make the connection
}
```

Comment: yes it's works, but it makes the delay become so bad. it becomes approx 10 times longer than when I use connection1 only..

Comment: please help me sir :(

Comment: This depends entirely on the connection timeout setting for the MySql driver. Googling "MySql .net Connection Timeout" gives many hits including this one from the Microsoft forum - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/740d5640-ad8f-40e0-b942-dadf9f141b54/mysqlconnection-timeout?forum=csharpgeneral.